# highcharts adding a date pointStart from date in php?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I have managed to make a column chart appear with values from a php array, the values are total expenditure on a particular day on holiday (a travel budget app I am making). How can I make the series pointStart from a date (start of the holiday) which I have retreived from the database and stored in a php variable? and also make each interval a new day?
I have made an attmept where the pointStart does not work.

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart2',
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Days of trip',
        data:  [<?php echo join($trip_total, ',') ?>],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date1 ?>),
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
    }]
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to echo PHP inside of a JavaScript file it will not work.

Comment: What "does not work"? What is wrong? The concept you are showing should be sufficient.

Comment: How your data looks like in the output? I mean this variable:  data:  [<?php echo join($trip_total, ',') ?>],

Comment: that bit looks fine, it displays the total spent on each day whihc is what I want, its the dates on the axis that i need to change

Comment: the pointStart and intervals on the axis, they do not work. I want them to display the date for each piece of data, but they do not at the moment

Comment: what is the value of **$date1**? Date.UTC requires (at least) three comma separated integers representing year, month, and day.

Comment: thats why i thought it would work because $date1 is 2016-03-11, all my dates in my database are stored in the format Y-m-d

Comment: You Can Try This [PHP Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974138/highcharts-adding-a-date-pointstart-from-date-in-php) I Think This Is Correct information What You Want